# DJANGO: how to extract all elements from a table that don't appear in another table

Tags: django, django-models

I have to admit that I got pretty rusty with django, so I'm sorry if the question is too simple.

I have a couple of models like the followings:

```
class Monograph(models.Model):
    monid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=2000)
    .............

class Isbn(models.Model):
    isbnid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    monid = models.ForeignKey(Monograph, db_column='monid')
    isbnnum = models.CharField("ISBN", max_length=20)
    .............
```

What I want to extract is the list of Monographs that don't appear in the table of ISBN.

In SQL I would write this query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Monograph WHERE monid NOT IN (SELECT monid FROM Isbn)
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
Monograph.objects.exclude(monid__in=Isbn.objects.values_list('monid', flat=True))
```

See docs for [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and [`__in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Another way would be (I think this version would hit DB only once):

```
Monograph.objects.filter(isbns=None)
```

You'll need to specify `related_name='isbns'` on the foreign key from `Isbn` to `Monograph` for this to work. (See docs for details on [backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).)

Comment: Is that a good indicator of code quality? I was just lazy =) We're off by 13 seconds, btw (you were first).

Comment: @maz, After your comment update: sadly, I'm not sure if it will execute only one query for that line.